# network printer adding canon ir 2520 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing, canon

[image]Could anyone help me how to add my institute network printer? I have its ip: 172. something.something etc. I can print from my desktop from the printer when I am using windows from the same desktop but I am unable to  print when I am using ubuntu. I have read many threads and tried a lot but I am unable to connect and print. I have downloaded in home whatever here is said but I dont know how to install http://sgros.blogspot.in/2012/07/linux-and-canon-imagerunner-2520.html

Comment: Do you have a file called `install.sh` inside the archive that you downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

please go here [UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux | Canon](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html) and click to download and SAVE what will be linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz (released July 2017).

1. open a terminal
2. copy the commands below; line by line; each separate; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

(to open a terminal, press three keys control, alt and t)
(to paste into a terminal, right-click at the flashing prompt in the terminal, and select PASTE from the menu ..)

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf  linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz
cd  linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken
sudo ./install.sh
```

(that last command starts the install script, that should do all the work; watch it; it will ask you some questions.. but it all should work)

Comment: Thanks..the last step didnt work :( :( I have added the picture in your answer

Comment: then use `sudo ./install.sh`      ... and it will ask you for your sudo password

Comment: Thank you ..It has been connected and detected but when I give a page for printing it doesnt do the job, in fact, when I give a print from my windows it wants a password and id for printing which we are given from the institute.

Comment: can you talk to the IT support at your institute about helping you now that the drivers are installed?